# Virtual inheritance with abstract middle class

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class, virtual-inheritance

This isn't a question about how to do something, I know well about virtual inheritance, and I know of a few ways to circumvent this problem - but none that I am happy about.

Here is some code that doesn't compile:

```
struct BottomClass
{
    BottomClass(int& ref) : ref(ref) {}
    int& ref;
};

struct MiddleClassA : virtual public BottomClass
{
    MiddleClassA() /*: BottomClass()*/ {}
    virtual ~MiddleClassA() = 0;
};

MiddleClassA::~MiddleClassA(){}

struct MiddleClassB : virtual public BottomClass
{
    MiddleClassB() /*: BottomClass()*/ {}
    virtual ~MiddleClassB() = 0;
};

MiddleClassB::~MiddleClassB(){}

struct TopClass final : public MiddleClassA, public MiddleClassB
{
    TopClass(int& ref) : BottomClass(ref) {}
};

void main()
{
    int someInt;
    TopClass variable(someInt);
}
```

What bothers me is why this doesn't compile. I know that there is no default constructor for BottomClass and hence MiddleClassX is ill-formed. But MiddleClassX are abstract classes! Even if I specified a constructor there it wouldn't be used under any circumstances... so why should I specify that?

I couldn't even give a sensible constructor there because MiddleClassX doesn't have any reasonable value to give to the BottomClass.

My question is: is there an elegant solution to this problem?

---

I have a few solutions myself, but I don't like any of them especially:

1) I could create a BottomClass default constructor that uses some garbage value to construct its ref. And then assert() in that constructor so I know it is never called... Of course this leads to me having to do run-time checking of everything that should be a compile-time error, and it also practically demands the existence of a garbage integer to get the reference of.

2) I could pass the reference to every abstract middle class and use that... But this leads to serious repetition of information, and when these chains get long (as they do) it is very tedious to maintain that. There is also the performance hit of having to pass an extra variable to every class.

(I apologize if my question is hard to understand - if anyone can better describe my dilemma that would be awesome, I'm challenged to put this into words)

Answer (score 1):

> Even if I specified a constructor there it wouldn't be used under any circumstances

Wrong. Constructors on abstract classes are used by derived classes. Abstract classes can still require initialization after all, the only thing special about abstract classes is that you can't *directly* construct them; only derived classes are allowed to construct them, and only as part of their own construction.

An abstract class with no constructors can't be derived, just like any other class with no constructors can't be derived.

Your second solution is the right one. If the constructors up the chain are inlined then there is no performance hit at all.

(By the way, this has nothing at all to do with virtual inheritance. You will run into the same problem with non-virtual inheritance.)

Comment: Okay, what I mean then is: replace the constructors with
MiddleClassX() : BottomClass(((std::cout << "Print me"), somegarbageint)) {}
Now, there is no situation in which that "Print me" would ever be printed without modifying the original classes.

Comment: Perhaps you aren't remembering the differences between virtual inheritance and the non-virtual one? A virtually inherited base class requires an *explicit construction from EVERY class down the chain of derived classes... My issue is with that because I NEED to specify the constructor in places where it will be forced to be overridden anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I am nearly positive this only applies to virtual inheritance. It's just, if you think it doesn't then I probably miscommunicated my question...

Answer (score 1):

Why not declare a default constructor...

```
BottomClass();  // deliberately undefined; use Bottom(int&)
```

...and leave it undefined - at worst you get a link-time error if an actual attempt to use it is made.

See on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/ZORi1U)

Comment: That doesn't compile for me (Visual Studio 2013). It would be awesome if it did!
But... it kinda surprises me that it works on ideone, actually...

Comment: @Ace24713 Might try prefixing with `template <class T>` then... should only be instantiated if actually called....

Comment: I actually thought of that earlier, but no luck. It still tries to link to it. If there is any evidence that that code should compile by c++ standards I'd write a bug report and be done with it?

Comment: One last idea: try making the `MiddleClassX` constructors templates too.  Re Standard - not the sort of thing I could swear to off the top of my head, so I'll leave you to check that side as I'm pretty busy ;-P.

Comment: Still no luck. (but honestly, even if that worked it would be so contrived I'd be inclined to call it a VS bug) Thanks though!

Comment: What about defining the constructor but failing all invocations of it with `static_assert`? This would at least give a better error message if it does get used accidentally.

Comment: @cdhowie: nice idea - I gave it a try at http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/ with VC++ 19.00.22203(x86) but it tripped the assertion every time... :-/